# How can I tell which language was detected with HighlightJS?

Tags: angularjs, highlight.js

For what it's worth, I'm using angularjs and https://github.com/pc035860/angular-highlightjs. I want to know which language was detected and if there's any way to do this.

If this library doesn't do it, are there any that do?

Comment: How are you using it ? Share some code.

Comment: I'm not using it yet, I plan to

Comment: On what does it depend?

Comment: On how you are going to use it (in a directive, in a service etc). How you are going to "bootstrap" it etc. The question is very unclear and broad to get a useful answer. Try something yourself and come but with more concrete problems/questions/requirements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could search for the `hljs` class with JavaScript and then find the language class associated with it (**assuming the language class is the last class**). Example with jQuery:

```
function findLanguageOfHLJSWithID(id) {
  var foundClasses = jQuery('#' + id + '.hljs').attr('class').split(' ');
  return foundClasses[foundClasses.length - 1];
}
```

If you want all the languages highlighted on the page, use this function:

```
function findAllHLJSLanguages() {
  var tempClasses = jQuery('.hljs'), foundClasses = [];
  for (var iter = 0; iter < tempClasses.length; iter++) {
    var tempClassesSplit = $(tempClasses[iter]).attr('class').split(' ');
    foundClasses.push(tempClassesSplit[tempClassesSplit.length - 1]);
  }
  return foundClasses;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the class `.hljs` extraneous as the ID alone will do?

Comment: Yes, but if we are searching using the class `hljs`, there could be more than one result if the OP has many Highlighter divs on one page.